# PDO and IS NOT NULL Function

Tags: mysql, null, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO and I was wondering if there was an equivalent to a mysql statement that checks if a parameter is not null such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE param IS NOT NULL
```

I tried this:

```
$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $tablename . ' WHERE ' . $field . ' = :' . $field . 'AND param IS NOT NULL');
```

without any success.
I also looked on the web, but did not find anything relevan, can anyone help please ?

Comment: You need a space before your AND (so `' AND...'` not `'AND...'`).

Comment: thanks I did not noticed that either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any query in pdo that you could use in mysql directly but your way of doing it is defeating the purpose of using PDO in the first place, you should phrase the query as

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE field = :field AND param IS NOT NULL");
$q->execute(array('field' => $field));
```

Comment: thanks, this was also what I used, in fact the issue lied somewhere else, the param was not set for having NULL values => schoolboy error!!

Comment: All kind of weird stuff happens, pay a bit more attention to error messages, set up a log for everything you're using (php, mysql, etc) and when something doesn't work look at the tail of the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Is…

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE :field IS NOT NULL";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':field', $field);
```

…What you're looking for?

Comment: I'm almost certain you can not bind a fieldname, just values. Prepared statements require predefined table and field names.